# Microsoft Phone Companioin

Tags: apps, windows-10, file-transfer, windows-10-mobile

This isn't about Windows Phone specifically, but I think it's something we're gonna start running into more and more as people upgrade to Windows 10.

Has anyone found an actual use for the Microsoft Phone Companion app? It seems to have replaced the Windows Phone app, which was nice for transferring photos and music, etc. But all that seems to have been removed from the Phone Companion app, leaving it powerless to do anything but tell me my phone and PC are "the perfect pair." Are we still able to somehow transfer files with it? Or really, use it for *anything*? If not, what is the best option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to have a use for most people, other than telling you how wonderful your phone is.

Recently an update has been pushed out so that the Photos app can also handle connects from a Windows Phone, and automatically sync new photos and videos (so what the old Windows Phone app could do). When the updated app was installed, the next time you connect your phone (and unlock it, when applicable) you get a notification telling you "new apps have been installed" with the choice to change the app you use. You can also change the default app via **Settings** > **Devices** > **Autoplay**

One reason I've found for Windows Phone Companion to be the default is for developers - If you don't have the Windows Phone Companion running, you may have issues deploying and debugging apps to connected phones.